# Is there a way to copy FormDesign appearance from one button to the next?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, formatting, appearance

So I created a lot of buttons (a-z). Unfortunately, when I reopened the document later, they're all blacked out and I'm having to go through and individually change the buttons appearance one at a time.

Is there a 'format painter' of some kind in visual studio express so that I can just change one's appearance, then copy that over to each next button?

Comment: Can you not select (Shift+Click) all of them and then set the properties you want?

Comment: LOL. I think you're on to something here. hahaha. 

That will probably work. :P Let me give it a go and I'll let you know. I'll let you post that as an 'answer' and I'll vote it as 'the' answer to give you some points for this simple suggestion.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe -- it does indeed work. :) Thank you. Please post that as an answer and I'll vote you up for it. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Forms, WPF and other UI designers in Visual Studio allow you to select multiple controls at once, by Ctrl+Click, Shift+Click or by dragging a selection ("rubber band") rectangle around the relevant controls.

Once you've done that, the properties editor displays those properties that the controls have in common. Changing a property changes it for all of the selected  controls.

Comment: Thank you a ton. It's funny - I knew I could multi-select items, but for whatever reason, I didn't even think about multi-selecting to change all properties. LOL. 

:)